# htmlentities not converting html tags

Tags: php, forms, validation, html-entities

When I submit the form, PHP echoes out tags exactly as I have written them instead of converting them into htmlentities. What is the problem?

PHP:

```
<?php

$name = htmlentities(substr($_POST["name"], 0, 100), ENT_QUOTES);
$email = htmlentities(substr($_POST["email"], 0, 100), ENT_QUOTES);
$msg = htmlentities(substr($_POST["message"], 0, 500), ENT_QUOTES);

echo ($name.'<br>'.$email.'<br>'.$msg);
```

HTML:

```
  <html>

  <body>

      <form role="form" action="test.php" method="POST">

            <p>Name:<input type="text" placeholder="Name" maxlength="100" name="name"></p>

            <p>Email address:<input type="text" placeholder="Email" maxlength="100" name="email"></p>

            <p>Message:<textarea rows="4" name="message" placeholder="Message" maxlength="500"></textarea></p>

              <input type="submit" value="submit">

        </form>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: @Quentin I have labels, fieldsets, etc. in my production form but wrote a separate test page to just to test htmlentities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You type the text `<example>`
2. You submit to the PHP
3. The PHP converts to the text `&lt;example&gt;`
4. The browser gets an HTML document containing the HTML source code `&lt;example&gt;`
5. The browser parses the HTML and:

   1. Treats `&lt;` as an instruction to display a `<` in the document
   2. Treats `example` as text to display
   3. Treats `&gt;` as an instruction to display a `>` in the document

If `htmlentities` had no effect, then `<example>` would be treated as an unknown tag and you would see nothing.

If you want to convert to HTML entities and then *display* the entities *in an HTML document*, then you'll need to run them through `htmlentities` **twice**.

Comment: Does this mean that htmlentities are actually working?

Comment: Yes, unless I've misunderstood the question and my answer doesn't describe what you're seeing in your browser.

Comment: When I put in <p>words</p> in one of the fields and hit submit, it echoes just that instead of &lt;words&gt;

Comment: Does it put `<p>words</p>` in the *rendered HTML document* or the source code you see in view source?

Comment: Ah I see. I viewed the source and saw the expected output. Then I wrapped the echo string in htmlentities and saw the expected output on my HTML page. Looks like it does work - thanks for the help.